# Set multiple languages for spell check in Slack

Tags: linux-mint, language, spell-check, slack

Is it possible to set multiple languages for spell check in Slack? Currently, the spell check is set to English, but I would also like to add Polish.

My OS is Linux Mint, and in Language Settings the language is set to "English, United States". I don't see an option to set multiple languages there.

Comment: I would guess that if it is not an option in the options dialog, then it is not an option.

Comment: This is a highly relevant option for me as well. Is this added by now?

Answer (score 5):

In the current version of the Slack app for windows (MSQ 4.16.1 for me), it's possible to select more than 1 language for spell checking. Just go to preferences > language & region > spellcheck.

[image: slack preferences screenshot]

Comment: I’m ashamed that my first reflex was to Google for this  OTOH I was expecting a simple right-click in the message field or something around it…

Comment: A note: it doesn't directly impact your text. I had to change conversation and come back again, then the spellcheck of my new text is done with both languages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you noticed that but recent versions of Slack on Linux allow to select multiple languages for a spell checker. No idea which version it was.

No idea if this is related but it showed up couple of months after creating this:
[image: Screenshot from slack support center with request to add multiple languages into spell checker]

Answer (score -1):

Most applications have their own Spell Checks as an Add-On like Firefox and most browsers. The same goes with text applications like Notepad++.
Not sure how is handled in that app. Slack, but check on their Add-Ons, Plugins or any other setting possibility.

You also might need your Keyboard Language layout added in the OS for Polish or the language you are interested.

I hope this helps.